# Still no answer Alarm Manager for push notification not working

Tags: android-studio

Hi guys Im trying to make a push notif using alarmmanager
for my simple voting system.
The problem is no notification showing.
whats wrong with this?
Also i notice that my   `mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)`
has warning says "Builder is deprecated" is that the reason why its not working?

this is my codes

AlerReciever class

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import.         android.support.v4.app.
```

NotificationCompat;

```
/**
 * Created by ivan on 2/27/2018.
*/

public class AlertReceiver extends.             B.     

 BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(
 Context context, Intent.          intent) {
    createNotification(context,"Voting.    System","
  Congrats to winner","Alert" );

 }

 public void createNotification(Context context,         

String msg
 ,String msgText, String msgAlert){
    PendingIntent notificIntent =       

 PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,
            new Intent(context,        

  AddCandidate.class),0);

      NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new.   

  NotificationCompat.Builder(context)


 .setSmallIcon(R.
  drawable.ic_account_circle_black_2. 4dp)
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setTicker(msgAlert)
            .setContentText(msgText);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);
          mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.
     DEFAULT.   _SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =        

   (NotificationManager) 
   context.getSystemService(context.
   NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
      }
    }
```

button

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new.                             

   View.OnClickListener() 
   {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Long alertTime =        

   GregorianCalendar.getInstance().
    getTimeInMillis()+5*1000;
            Intent alertIntent = new.   

   Intent(AddCandidate.this, AlertReceiver.class);
            AlarmManager alarmManager =   

  (AlarmManager)getSystemService(
 Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
               alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.
 RTC_WAKEUP,    alertTime,           

  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
 AddCandidate.this, 1,alertIntent,

 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
            Toast.makeText(AddCandidate.this, "ll",     

   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     });
```

Manifest

```
 xmlns:android="
  http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.ivan.votingsystem">

  <uses-permission.   android:name="android.
  permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission.  android:name="
 android.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="
 @mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="
   android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="
   android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Dashboard" />
    <activity android:name=".AddCandidate"/>
    <activity android:name=".VoteNow"></activity>

  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Any one? 8 hrs since i post this pls

Comment: Any one can answer this?

Comment: yup that's the reason, replace it with NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL) using support library and create a notification channel according to the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification . Without both of these notifications won't be picked up by the system